# DynamoDB increment a key/value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

if I was to have a DynamoDB table with a UserID as a key and a number as a value can I increment that number/value in a single operation? or do I need to read it out, increment and write it back in?

thx

Answer (score 31, accepted):

DynamoDB supports the concept of atomic counters.  You would simply call update_item with `action: "ADD"` to automatically increment the value for an item.

Comment: But this is different, works to increment an existing entry not for a create_item, that seems to me what the user is checking on...

Comment: You can call UpdateItem with action:ADD on a row that does not exist. It will create the row and set the attribute to 0 before doing the ADD operation. A create_item is not required

Comment: Thank you @prestomation, that was what I was hoping to hear!

Comment: how does that work for setting the range key as auto incrementing?

Comment: How the concurrency works on it, if 2 calls are calling ADD action with +1 are intersecting with each other. Does DynamoDb handles doing +2 for total and ensures it will done correctly, or there can be an error.

Answer (score 39):

As others have stated, you can increment with one operation, however "action: ADD" is now deprecated. The current way to achieve this is with UpdateExpression. I am also assuming the OP meant that there was a numeric [attribute] whose value needs incrementing. I am calling the attribute loginCount:

```
dynamoDB.updateItem({
  TableName: "Users",
  Key: { "UserId": { S: "c6af9ac6-7b61" } },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":inc": {N: "1"} },
  UpdateExpression: "ADD loginCount :inc"
})
```

Answer (score 3):

It is no longer recommended to use `ADD`, instead the recommendation is to use `SET`. See [the docs for UpdateExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html)

For example (in JavaScript where `client` is a DynamoDB client) you would `try`:

```
const result = await client.send(new UpdateItemCommand({
  TableName: process.env.DB_FORMS_TABLE,
  Key: marshall({
    userId: "c6af9ac6-7b61"
  }),
  UpdateExpression:
    "SET loginCount = loginCount + :loginChange",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: marshall({
    ":loginChange": 1
  }),
  ReturnValues: "NONE",
}));
```

This is a somewhat contrived example as you're only adding 1, but note that you can use `-` instead of `+` and add/subtract any numeric value without needing to read the old value first.

Also, as this is an `UpdateItemCommand`, if there is no record with that key (`userId`), it will create (`Put`) one with that key and a new `loginCount` of 1 in this case. This can be a very useful feature.

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html) recommend using `SET` as above rather than the alternative way using `ADD` (note that you can `ADD` a negative number, there is no `SUBTRACT`!)

If you want to know the new counter value, pass `"ALL_NEW"` instead of `"NONE"` for `ReturnValues` and it will be in the response.

Comment: >Also, as this is an `UpdateItemCommand`, if there is no record with that key (`userId`), it will create (`Put`) one with that key and a new loginCount of 1 in this case. This can be a very useful feature. \n \n

This is simply not true. The UpdateExpression `SET loginCount = loginCount + :loginChange` expects the item to be there only then you can use SET for incrementing or decrementing numbers. However, if you are not incrementing or decrementing, then what you are saying is true.

Comment: Here is what the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement:~:text=existing%20numeric%20attribute) says: "You can add to or subtract from an **existing numeric attribute**."

Comment: The good news is that you can use ADD if you want the behavior to add or subtract and you also don't know if the attribute or the key itself already exists in the table or not. For this reason, I believe ADD is the only way to go. [Official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD:~:text=add%20a%20new%20attribute%20and%20its%20values%20to%20an%20item): 
"Use the ADD action in an update expression to add **a new attribute** and its values to an item"

Comment: However, you can use something like `SET countN = if_not_exists(countN, :zero) + :updatedVal` with UpdateItem. In this case, DDB will PUT if `countN` or the `PK` doesn't exist. 

Sorry for so many comments, I guess a new answer would have been better :-)

Comment: Yes I believe my answer (and official docs) recommends using SET not ADD, and a strong reason is indeed because if there is no existing value, it will PUT (i.e. create) one. So you don't need to do `if_not_exists` etc.

Comment: "*So you don't need to do if_not_exists etc.*" That's precisely what I am trying to explain -- you **do** need to do `if_not_exists` with SET when using the `path` on the RHS of the `UpdateExpression`.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

To me the other answers are not clear in specifically what is currently best practice for incrementing an attribute without knowing if the item exists. (For that matter the AWS documentation isn't clear either.) In particular the dispute over whether `if_not_exists(…)` is needed never was resolved in an answer—only in comments.

So to help others, I've tried the various things mentioned in the other answers, and here is the best approach: use [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html) with a [`SET` update expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET), but you have to use `if_not_exists()`. It looks like this, as @NityaSheth [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077414/dynamodb-increment-a-key-value/76879110#comment135153422_76182873):

```
SET #count = if_not_exists(#count, :zero) + :one
```

- Map `#count` to the correct *expression attribute name* (or use an attribute name you know is valid for expressions).
- Map `:zero` and `:one` to number attribute values `0` and `1`, respectively (e.g. `AttributeValue.fromN("0")` and `AttributeValue.fromN("1")` in the AWS Java SDK 2.x).

It bears emphasizing that `UpdateItem` `SET` will *not* automatically create the item if it does not exist. If you leave out `if_not_exists(…)`, DynamoDB returns an error:

> The provided expression refers to an attribute that does not exist in the item

Finally I see nowhere in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD) where it says that `ADD` is "deprecated", despite one of the other answers here. The documentation currently says:

> In general, we recommend using `SET` rather than `ADD`.

A recommendation (and in fact a "general" recommendation, implying "most of the time"—not a complete recommendation) is completely different than deprecation. There is no recommendation that one should *not* use `ADD`, and there is certainly no indication on that page that `ADD` will be going away. Nevertheless, as it appears there is a way to make this work with the recommended action `SET`, that's the one I prefer.

Answer (score -13):

If you are looking for something like MySQL's Auto Increment functionality, then No, that is not possible in DynamoDB.